# WPF Render size issue at debugging

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a strange problem with wpf render size, trying to write custom template for radio button so it can scale with resolution.
In VS XAML preview it looks like it should, but when i run the application it goes bananas.

This is VS preview:

[image: Preview]

Application:

[image: App]

So as much as i can see problem is in render size:

[image: Grid render size]

[image: Rectangle]

I did try without grid, with Height and Width set to auto and so on, every time it renders in VS preview with no problems at all, but soon as i debug it (F5) it just goes to some huge render size value. Resizing the window makes no difference.

XAML code:

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                        <BulletDecorator>
                            <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                <Border   Background="{x:Null}" x:Name="PART_Border" Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ButtonPanel}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ButtonPanel}"


                                >
                                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                            <Rectangle Margin="{Binding 
                                                Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                                ElementName=ButtonPanel, 
                                                Path=ActualHeight, 
                                                ConverterParameter=0.03}" 
                                       Fill="{x:Null}" 
                                       RadiusX="{Binding 
                                                Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                                ElementName=ButtonPanel, 
                                                Path=ActualHeight, 
                                                ConverterParameter=0.10}" 
                                       RadiusY="{Binding 
                                                Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                                ElementName=ButtonPanel, 
                                                Path=ActualHeight, 
                                                ConverterParameter=0.10}" 
                                       Stroke="#FFE0E000"
                                       StrokeThickness="{Binding 
                                                Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                                ElementName=ButtonPanel, 
                                                Path=ActualHeight, 
                                                ConverterParameter=0.07}"  
                                       Width="{Binding 
                                                Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                                ElementName=ButtonPanel, 
                                                Path=ActualHeight, 
                                                ConverterParameter=0.94}"  
                                       Height="{Binding 
                                                Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                                                ElementName=ButtonPanel, 
                                                Path=ActualHeight, 
                                                ConverterParameter=0.94}"  
                                       />

                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        </BulletDecorator>


                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Thank you

Comment: For extra points, can i add my custom attributes in the radio button template, like text font, color of the rectangle stroke, image inside rectangle and so on? :)

Comment: Check if you parsing your '0.94' good, if you have "invariant culutre" in your converter, then 0.94 will be 94. This can be the issue.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in a value converter, if someone has the same problem here's the solution:

```
    public class PercentageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value,
            Type targetType,
            object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            double _value = Double.Parse(value.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            double _parameter = Double.Parse(parameter.ToString(), culture);
            return _value * _parameter;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value,
            Type targetType,
            object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```